# Bitwise operator with negative numbers

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Why does..

```
-23&30 = 8
5&-3 = 5 
15&-1 = 15
```

I understand & with positive numbers but for some reason when a negative number is thrown, I don't understand how the answer is derived.

Comment: Do you know about how negative numbers are represented in binary in Java? (i.e. two's complement)

Comment: Negative numbers are represented by their two's complement.

Comment: What result were you expecting? Why?

Comment: Write those numbers in binary and do the AND operation by yourself. You'll get it

Answer (score 4):

You should read about 2's complement method of representing negative numbers in binary.

For example:

```
 5 == 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
 &
-3 == 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
 =    -----------------------------------
 5 == 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
```